# Antd Design - позиция иконки в компоненте Notification

Tags: reactjs, ant-design

Я использую Ant Design для создания компонента Notification. Мне нужно, чтобы он был высотой 40 пикселей, поэтому я добавил несколько стилей, и теперь мой компонент выглядит так:

```
import React from 'react';
import { notification } from 'antd';
import { CheckOutlined, CloseOutlined, QuestionOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const NotificationComponent = ({ options }) => {

  const icons = {
    'success': <CheckOutlined style={{ color: "#fff" }} />,
    'failure': <CloseOutlined style={{ color: "#fff" }} />,
    'info': <QuestionOutlined style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
  }

  const openNotification = () => {
      notification.open({
        message: (
          <div style={{ color: "#fff", position: "absolute", top: '6px', bottom: 0, lineHeight: '40px' }}>
              <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{ options.text }</p>
          </div>
        ),
        icon: icons[options.icon],
        closable: false,
        duration: 500,
        placement: 'top',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: options.icon === "success" ? "#6FCF97" : (
            options.icon === "failure" ? "#FF708B" : "#828EE3"
          ),
          height: "40px",
          margin: 0
        }
      });
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={openNotification}>Показать уведомление</button>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default NotificationComponent;
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно, чтобы мой значок уведомления был выше, что я пытался сделать через отрицательный margin, но это не работает. В данный момент это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это можно как-то исправить? 
P.S. ссылка на code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-euler-5j9nq6?file=/src/Notification.jsx:0-1189